# Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, typeorm, rest

I am learning typeorm with expressjs. Here I am trying to implement `login` user function where if user exist it will send an access token. I have already implemented Register function but while adding login I get error in console saying this. I have no idea what this means.

```
(node:8536) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(node:8536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isValidPassword' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\adity\Desktop\dev\restapi\src\controllers\AuthController.ts:43:15)
    at step (C:\Users\adity\Desktop\dev\restapi\src\controllers\AuthController.ts:32:23)
    at Object.throw (C:\Users\adity\Desktop\dev\restapi\src\controllers\AuthController.ts:13:53)
    at rejected (C:\Users\adity\Desktop\dev\restapi\src\controllers\AuthController.ts:5:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:8536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8536) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here is my code.

> AuthController.ts

```
static login = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    if (!(email && password)) {
      res.status(400).send();
    }

    const userRepository = getRepository(User);
    let user: User;
    try {
      user = await userRepository.findOneOrFail({ where: email });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(401).send(error);
    }
    if (!user.isValidPassword(password)) {
      res.status(401).send("Incorrect Password");
      return;
    }
    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id, email: user.email }, "secret", {
      expiresIn: "1h",
    });
    res.send(token);
  };
```

> Entity/User.ts

```
import * as bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  @Length(4, 100)
  password: string;

  @Column()
  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column()
  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  isValidPassword = (password: string) => {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
  };

  setPassword = (password: string) => {
    return (this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 8));
  };
}
```

Comment: is `getRepository(User)` a synchronous or asynchronous function?

Comment: asynchronous function. It is provided by typeorm.

Comment: in the case, perhaps its best to attach a catch block to it like so:

`const userRepository = await getRepository(User).catch(err=>console.log(err));`

Comment: https://typeorm.io/#/working-with-repository

Comment: are you sure the unhandles promise rejection error is related to this AuthController file??

Comment: I am not sure i am just following https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/creating-a-rest-api-with-jwt-authentication-and-role-based-authorization-using-typescript-fbfa3cab22a4 tutorial I am new to backend development.

Answer (score 0):

This NodeJS error usually happens when its detecting an asynchronous function somewhere in your code whose error is not being handled.

If `getRepositry(user)` is an async function, you could try attaching a catch block it like so:

```js
const userRepository = await getRepository(User).catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

This should take care of unhandled promise rejection error.

Comment: can't add this. this gives error. Here you can learn about `getRepository` https://typeorm.io/#/working-with-repository

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in case `findOneOrFail` could not find any user it will through error that you are catching but it will result in user value equal to undefined.

Then the method `isValidPassword` will not work as it is not defined on the `undefined` but on the `user` model

```
if (!user.isValidPassword(password)) {
      res.status(401).send("Incorrect Password");
      return;
}
```

you should move above code in the try block or you can place a type guard in front like this

```
if (user && !user.isValidPassword(password)) {
          res.status(401).send("Incorrect Password");
          return;
}
```